# Why is the Camera API only in English? (The “Cancel”, “Auto”, “Retake”, “Use” buttons; and “Move and Scale” label.)

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I’m using `UIImagePickerController` to pop up a camera that allows minor editing (moving and scaling) of the image afterwards.

My question is: How can I customize the “Cancel”, “Auto”, “Retake”, “Use” buttons—and “Move and Scale” label—to appear in another language?

I tried changing the iPhone’s language settings to another language, but the camera in my app remains in English. (But in any case, I don’t really want users to have to change system languages; my app comes in one and only one language and it’s not English—even if their iPhone system language is set to English.)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Go to your project Settings > Info and change `Localization native development region` from English to your Language. It will change the language of Apple Componants.

Answer (score 4):

you can localise camera cancel button, done button by adding this key in info.plist

```
 <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>en,ru</string>
```